# After first ajax request then run second one.. Now same time run both function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax functionality which run tow request same time. I want run these function not same time, After first success run second ajax request

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:'Post',
    data : {'first':first},
    url : 'abc.php',
    success : function (returnHtml) {
        jQuery(".xyz").html(returnHtml);
    }

});

jQuery.ajax({
    type:'Post',
    data : {'first':first},
    url : 'abc1.php',
    success : function (returnHtml) {
        jQuery(".xyz2").html(returnHtml);
    }

});
```

How can do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User async in jquery

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:'Post',
    async : false,
    data : {'first':first},
    url : 'abc.php',
    success : function (returnHtml) {
        jQuery(".xyz").html(returnHtml);
    }

});

jQuery.ajax({
    type:'Post',
    async : false,
    data : {'first':first},
    url : 'abc1.php',
    success : function (returnHtml) {
        jQuery(".xyz2").html(returnHtml);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the second ajax request in success function of first ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type:'Post',
     data : {'first':first},
     url : 'abc.php',
    success : function (returnHtml)
    {
      jQuery(".xyz").html(returnHtml);
           jQuery.ajax({
                        type:'Post',
                        data : {'first':first},
                        url : 'abc1.php',
                             success : function (returnHtml) 
                                       {
                                       jQuery(".xyz2").html(returnHtml);
                                      }

                         });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the two of these in function. Say Function A and Function B. In the `success :` part of function A, call function B.

Answer (score 0):

You can put second AJAX call inside the `success` callback of first AJAX call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    data: {
        'first': first
    },
    url: 'abc.php',
    success: function (returnHtml) {
        jQuery(".xyz").html(returnHtml);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            data: {
                'first': first
            },
            url: 'abc1.php',
            success: function (returnHtml) {
                jQuery(".xyz2").html(returnHtml);
            }
        });
    }
});
```